# What parameters does window.open accept?

Tags: javascript

How can I add the following parameters to a `window.open()` call? I'm not sure how they should be named.

```
*I don't want a toolbar
*I don't want a menu bar
*I don't want a status bar
*I want a scrollbar
*I don't want the user to be able to resize
```

The following is my current code for opening a window:

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function OLA(url) 
    {
      params  = 'width=290';
      params += ', height='+(parseInt(screen.availHeight) * .9355);
      params += ', top=0, left=0';
      params += ', fullscreen=no';

      newwin=window.open(url,'windowname4', params);
      if (window.focus) {newwin.focus()}
      return false;
    }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="OLA('ANO_1_InitialAssessment.html')">Start Here</a>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those parameters you can add to your strings:

```
toolbar=off     //I don't want a toolbar
resizable=off   //I don't want the user to be able to resize
menu=off        //I don't want a menu bar
status=off      //I don't want a status bar
scrollbars=on   //I want a scrollbar
```

I recommend to check the `window.open` page on the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), it will list all parameters, along with their support.

**NOTE: not all parameters work the same way on all browsers**.

Comment: How would I add those params into the code that I provided? I have put them in the newwin=window.open after the params but they did not work. I have also added them to the string of information params += ', fullscreen=no' and it also did not work.

Comment: just add them along with other parameters, separated by a comma, like this: `params += ',toolbar=on, resizable=on, menu=on, status, scrollbars=off'`. Also remember that **these won't work on all browsers**, the MDN page explains that too, for example, chrome blocks many of these options.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance though we are using this in IE it is still not working. I will try to figure out another way.